# I added a key pair to my Beanstalk instance so I could SSH in and now it's failing health checks and won't communicate with the front end

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I had an instance of a backend server for my website running on elastic beanstalk, using RDS and communicating with a front end instance.  I needed to add a file to the server so I downloaded ebs command line tool and set up ssh.  To do this it had to create a key pair and then remake the instance(not a step I really understand) After that, the server stopped responding to the front end, and it is failing all Health checks.

The health check says: "100.0 % of the requests are erroring with HTTP 4xx. Insufficient request rate (18.0 requests/min) to determine application health.
ELB health is failing or not available for all instances."

I tried to remove the key pair, but it fails to launch an instnce that doesn't have the key pair now.  Do I need to put the key pair in other places so that the front end can communicate? Why would the health checks start failing?  That is the setting I changed that broke everything.  I played around with security groups to no avail.  I don't know what other information would be helpful to add here, but I'll be quick to edit my post if you tell me.

P.S. I tried paying for AWS technical support and it said they'd get back to me within 12 hours, but it's been more than a day.  Is that a pattern with them?

Comment: Why do you mean by "remake the instance"?

Comment: I don't know entirely, but when I ran the line ebs ssh --setup, it said something about having to delete and make a new version of the instance